# Saving image picked from gallery

Tags: android, android-intent

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18668433/1991579). Perfect work on almost devices.
But doesn't work at Samsung Galaxy 3.

On normal device i have something like **content://media/external/images/media/1** in **intent.getData()**  and after using **getContentResolver()** i have **/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/package/.../file.jpg**

But on Samsung Galaxy 3 in **intent.getData()** i have **content://com.sec.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/5624862738518543714**  and **https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-22xcQIWrlT4/Tg-G29-6jWI/AAAAAAAAAJA/i_FUO3pN1Sc/I/%2525D0%252597%2525D0%2525B0_%2525D0%2525B5%2525D0%2525B4%2525D1%252583.jpg**  after using Resolver.

What should i do to get normal path on Samsung Galaxy 3?

**UPD:** i see, in gallery there is available to pick pictures from my Google+ shared pictures. Hm...

So, i think, i will show message for users in this case to pick only local files.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248265/camera-intent-not-working-with-samsung-galaxy-s3/15287164#15287164) is of any interest.

Comment: @Nun'eChai nop, but tnx for answer)

Comment: Regretful, you can try putting a bounty on this question and maybe you get some insight.

Comment: @Nun'eChai i updated question, it was cause in gallery shows Google+ shared images as links. So i should show message for users in this case to pick only local files, i think.